# Python Pandas Retention Analysis Memory Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset setup like so:

[image]

The end result I want is:

[image]

I can't do this inside of my sql database because I don't have permissions for window functions or the ability to join to a calendar table etc.

I'm trying to achieve this using python like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('csv path')

df['CancelDt']=df['CancelDt'].fillna('2021-02-11', inplace=False)

df['DATE'] = [pd.date_range(s, e, freq='d') for s, e in

              zip(pd.to_datetime(df['InceptionDt']), pd.to_datetime(df['CancelDt']))]


df = df.explode('DATE').drop(['InceptionDt', 'CancelDt'], axis=1)

path = 'csv path'

df.to_csv(path+'retentionfull.csv')
```

But I can't get it to run without a memory error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\gamecompletewithcite.py", line 9, in <module>
    zip(pd.to_datetime(df['InceptionDt']), pd.to_datetime(df['CancelDt']))]
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3163, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3239, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3899, in _sanitize_column
    value = maybe_convert_platform(value)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 112, in maybe_convert_platform
    values = construct_1d_object_array_from_listlike(values)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 1638, in construct_1d_object_array_from_listlike
    result[:] = values
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 610, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self._data, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 102, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 556, in __array__
    return super().__array__(dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py", line 271, in __array__
    return np.array(list(self), dtype=object)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 579, in __iter__
    data[start_i:end_i], tz=self.tz, freq=self.freq, box="timestamp"
MemoryError
```

I'm wondering if there is more efficient way to process this or a setting I can change to get this to run properly. Here's my hardware:

AMD 3800x
16gb Ram
2070 Super

Comment: @jarlh yeah I agree this isn't really a SQL question, but if someone has a solution to this problem in SQL that doesn't involve window functions or calendar table joins I'd be all ears. I removed the tag. -Corgiraptor

Comment: If that one row is at all representative, you're looking to multiply the number of rows by approximately 5000, so I'd say expect to use about 1000x more memory than you currently are if you want to hold it all at once. Obviously you're going to have a problem unless your current dataset is tiny, so the only real solution might be to do each row at a time and then save the result, that way you process in chunks and don't require as much memory per operation

Comment: Right, I saw a solution somewhere else on stack overflow that involved a similar request and that had more rows than I did and they were able to run the entire program in 13 sec. I wish I could remember where that is but I know this is possible without using a terabyte of ram.